# How can we use AND & OR operators be used along with simple join?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, select, logical-operators

I have two tables in my database **CustomerAddresses** and **Area**.

**Columns of CustomerAddresses are -**

- id (Primary Key),
- areaId (foreign key with reference to table Areas),
- CustomerId,
- addressLine1,
- addressLine2,
- landmark,
- pincode,
- preferred,

**Columns of Areas are -**

- areaId (Primary Key),
- name,

```
 SELECT * FROM CustomerAddresses CA, Areas A 
 WHERE CA.areaId = A.areaId
 AND 
 CA.customerId = 1 
 AND 
 ( CA.addressLine1 like 'd'
 OR 
   CA.addressLine2 like 'd' 
 OR 
   CA.landmark like 'd' 
 OR 
   CONVERT(pincode, CHAR) like 'd' 
 OR 
   A.name like 'd' );
```

I want to pick up all the addresses of one customer from CustomerAddresses and then want to search whether the character 'd' is present in those records.

Query returning empty set.

Comment: you should add the `%`  operator   `like '%d%'`

Comment: You need wild cards: `LIKE %d%`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here isn't the join, it's the fact you're missing the wildcards before and after the `d` in your `like` calls:

```
CA.addressLine1        like '%d%' OR 
CA.addressLine2        like '%d%' OR 
CA.landmark            like '%d%' OR
CONVERT(pincode, CHAR) like '%d%' OR
A.name                 like '%d%' 
-- These --------------------^-^
```